# Nicely formatting long //comments in vim

Tags: vim, comments

When I am typing a long code comment in VIM, I manually judge when each comment line reaches 80 characters, then manually typically press < enter >< tab >//< space > and continue on. Likewise it is awkward editing comments, adding or removing text.

```
// The comments I have to use
// look like this
```

Ideally, I'd like some kind of comment mode, where you type text, and the 80 line character limit and the // symbols are sorted out automatically. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can turn on formatting options with `set formatoptions=tcq` (with tcq each representing an option, there are others as well). Use `h formatoptions` to see what the various flags are.

In this case you probably want to use `set fo+=a`.

Personally though, I prefer to just type my comments normally, then when I'm done run `gqip`. `gq` is the formatting command, `ip` for in paragraph. Make sure the comment block is not next to code though or it will suck that up when reformatting your comment.

Comment: Just want to mention that the [vim-textobj-comment](https://github.com/glts/vim-textobj-comment) plugin is a helpful solution to the "make sure the comment block is not next to code" problem—after installing just `gqic`.

Answer (score 8):

I use `:set textwidth=80` to set the formatting width (actually, 80 is the default).

Then I move the cursor to the first line of the comment and in command mode press `gq}` to format the comment.  It also works for other comment types from other programming languages such as `#` and `/* ... */`

Answer (score 5):

A variant on @Alex's suggestion is to select the lines in visual mode and then press `gq`. This allows you to avoid the problem of `gqip` reformatting code as well.

Pressing capital `V` selects an entire line, then you can just move up or down to highlight all the comments and press `gq`.